# Read undo history in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, undo

I have a fairly simple bit of VBA in Word 2003 that changes the document's font to an 'eco font' (long story), and brings up the Print dialog.

When a user hits Cancel or OK, the code does an 'undo' to revert the change.

The problem is, sometimes when I press "OK" to print the document, *two* actions need to be undone ('font change', and 'update fields'). I can't seem to predict when this will happen.

Is there any way of reading the last item in Word's undo buffer? That way I can just keep pressing undo until the font change has been completed.

**Edit:**
Final code (cut down):

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks.Add ("_tempEcoUndoStart_") 
ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Name = "Nanonymus Eco Sans" 
Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show 
While ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("_tempEcoUndoStart_") 
    ActiveDocument.Undo 
Wend
```

Comment: And obviously I can't just change the font back, because they might be using multiple fonts in a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a trick to have a 'transactional'-like undo in Word: At the beginning of the macro place a special bookmark on your entire document. You should remove this bookmark again when you are done with your macro. Now, when calling the Undo command, repeat the undo while there is your special bookmark in the document.

The following related question has the details:

> [**Can I create an undo transaction in Word or Excel? (VSTO)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661269/can-i-create-an-undo-transaction-in-word-or-excel-vsto)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but perhaps you can use UndoClear before your actions, and a count on undo after?

```
ActiveDocument.UndoClear
ActiveDocument.Undo 2
```

Comment: Probably, yeah, and I might have to. But it's not a particularly nice thing to do to a user :-(