# Is it possible to do Undo/Redo in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

My VSTO application is a C# Add-In. I would like to add some undo(Ctrl +z) and redo functionality(Ctrl +Y).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```cs
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Undo()

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Repeat()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a hidden document in conjunction with Range.WordOpenXML/.InsertXML with good success in Word. I can't say how well it would work with Excel. Here is my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661269/can-i-create-an-undo-transaction-in-word-or-excel-vsto/1157490#1157490) with some code samples.

Comment: I will if this idea is applicable to Excel