# How do I get back my original file after performing all the Operations on the excel file using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Can Anyone tell me how do I undo all my changes to my workbook?
I have file excel1.xlsx and I have did sorting and many operations on the excel.xlsx using vba. But at the end I want the excel1.xlsx to be the same which was at the start. How do i Undo all my changes using vba?

```
 activeworkbook.saved = True
```

I have found that it retains back all the contents as at the begginning but its not working.So is there any command where i can get back my original file after performing operations over it. Well yes

```
              wb1.Sheets(1).Activate
              ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

It works but I dont want my workbooks to be closed it should be still opened. How do I make it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building undo into an Excel VBA macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339228/building-undo-into-an-excel-vba-macro)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to undo a sub routine, you can either choose not to save the file and just close it, or you have to write a special sub routine to save the state of the file, then restore the state (custom undo). This is one of the pains with sub routines is that they cannot be undone through normal undo. Most people, me including, will reccomend you work off a backup.

When making your custome undo routine, the big question is what do you need to save the state for? Saving all information about the file would be unnessesarily heavy, so it's good to know what you want to save.

**Update**:
This is a dirty way to backup the sheet if you only have 1 sheet of data. This is more of a proof of concept of one way to create a backup and not finalized perfect code. It just creates a backup copy of the currentsheet and when you'restore' you are simply deleting the original sheet and renaming the backup to what it used to be called. :p

**How to test:**
Put some data and value in your original sheet then run the Test() sub-routine!

```
Public backupSheet As Worksheet
Public originalSheet As Worksheet
Public originalSheetName As String

Sub CreateBackup()
    Set originalSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    originalSheetName = originalSheet.Name
    originalSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
    Set backupSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    backupSheet.Name = "backup"
    originalSheet.Activate
End Sub

Sub RestoreBackup()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    originalSheet.Delete
    backupSheet.Name = originalSheetName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub ZerosFromHell()
    Range("A1:Z100").Select
    Cells.Value = 0
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Call CreateBackup
    Call ZerosFromHell
    MsgBox "look at all those darn 0s!"
    Call RestoreBackup
End Sub
```

Comment: Issun I have to undo all the changes I did. I should get back my original file like it was at the beginning it works if i say thisworkbook.close savedchanges:=false but i dont want it to be close It must be still opened becuase there are some operations i need to perform again ?

Comment: To be honest I never found a good undo routine. Normally I would just create a backup and revert to it, or just close and open again. I added a sloppy concept of how to create a backup of a single sheet (posted above).

Comment: Especially with the new autosave feature, I have found a need to do something like this.  I used this technique, but stored the original name of the sheet in an area not used or regularly rewritten.  Thus, each backup had its own original name.  I could have appended it to the backup name, but this was easier to test.  I had a backup routine built but was looking for a quick and dirty restore routine.  You had exactly what I needed.  Due to the sheet names involved, I also easily re-sorted it back to where it was originally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't. Sorry.

Changes you make to your sheet using VBA cannot be undone at the click of a button or with a single, standard VBA statement.

The right thing to do would seem to be: do your VBA-driven work on a copy of the sheet, and delete/don't save this copy if you don't want to keep the changes (and reopen the original if you need to do so). But from your question, it sounds like you don't want to do that.

Your only alternative is then to write your own VBA procedure that backtracks all the changes you've done. Depending on what operations you performed, reversing them could be a ridiculously complicated thing to do, compared to just closing without saving and re-opening. But if you insist, by all means, knock yourself out!

Answer (score 2):

1. Save a copy of the original workbook prior to running your macro. using the .SaveAs method at the beggining of the sub routine.
2. Run the VBA macro routine in the original workbook.
3. Now have a second macro "Undo VBA changes" that opens the workbook copy from step (1) , closes the workbook that ran the macro in Step (2) and calls the .SaveAs method again overwriting the existing workbook from step (2).

Note:
In order to get this UndoMacro to work you will need to put it in an Addin or a seperate workbook (an addin is cleaner). This will allow you to run the .SaveAs method and overwrite teh original workbook from Step (2) which will at this point have been closed to prevent an VBA runtime error message occuring.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your data is cleanly organized, this works pretty well. Much like the OP, I needed to go back to the original state of an Excel file, and didn't want to have to re-load the original (it takes about 25 seconds to load, due to aged infrastructure, and slow PCs).

What I did was to copy all of the data into a variant array, do all of my processing to the workbook, then write back the variant array to the Excel file (data is on a worksheet called "Data", and starts at Row 2, and uses columns A through Z).  While this uses a bit of RAM, the reading/writing is nearly instantaneous.  Relevant code:

```
Dim varDataArray As Variant, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lngEndRow as Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

With ws
 ' This simply finds the last row with data
 lngEndRow = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
 ' This reads all cell data from A2 to Z###, where ### is the last row
 varDataArray = .Range("A2:Z" & lngNumberOfRows).Value

 ... do things ...

 ' This writes all the data back to Excel
 ' 26 is the numeric column equivalent to "Z"
 .Range("A2").Resize(lngEndRow, 26) = varDataArray

End With
```