# How to undo macro task in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel 2010.

I have recorded following macro for playback (edited) and used customUI editor to make excel addin.

This is my first macro encounter with excel.

```
Sub Open1(control As IRibbonControl)
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SomeText"
End Sub
```

Why the task is not being recorded for redo?

[image]

Comment: VBA actions are not stored by the application and therefore cannot be undone. One of the tough learning points for me was always, always save my base data before running VBA changes!

Comment: Used to MS word which have memory to store changes even with VBAs. For excel Will keep in mind your advice

Comment: There is an undo function for vba, but you must store in he previous data and code the undo action yourself

Comment: I will search accordingly and try.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Can you give little more hint as I am completely novice in excel VBA

Comment: @Rahul [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/339263/445425)